# Add a string to the input space of the console

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, command-line-interface

I don't really know how to explain this so the title is probably misleading.

I'm making a small text editor in C and I'm saving the contents of an entire file into an array of chars. Now I want to display the entire string to the user in a way that the user will be able to edit the string inside the command window by positioning the cursor/seek and then typing or deleting characters. Pressing enter or some other key would save the text to a new string and write it to the file.

Similar to what happens when you open a file in a linux text editor like nano or vi... You get that cursor which you can move around the file and make changes.

How can that be done in C? I don't need it to be like in the linux editors, simply putting the string inside the input area (as if the user typed the text) would be  enough.

Comment: Simple C project in Visual Studio 2010. It's supposed to work only in Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use [Terminal capabilities (a.k.a Termcaps)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap). They are special characters which can be interpreted by your terminal (e.g moving the cursor back and forth, or clearing the screen). Here's what Wikipedia says about Termcap databases :

> A termcap database can describe the capabilities of hundreds of
>   different display terminals. This allows programs to have
>   character-based display output, independent of the type of terminal.
>   On-screen text editors such as vi and emacs are examples of programs
>   that may use termcap.

By using terminal capabilities, you will be able to control the way the cursor behaves in your editor, and how input characters shows up. A good example of this would be using colors for syntax highlighting.

I would suggest that you use the [GNU Termcap library](https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_node/termcap_toc.html) to build a cross-terminal application. Once you get the main principles, its usage is relatively straightforward, I used it back in the days to actually build a shell (such as `bash`, or `sh`).

Next, you might also want to look at the [differences](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Canonical-or-Not.html) between *canonical* and *non-canonical* terminal modes. Given what kind of functionalities you are wanting to implement in your editor, you will likely want to *override* the way your terminal interprets some inputs.

See also :

- [Moving the cursor using Termcaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_node/termcap_26.html)
- [Characters for Input Editing only available in canonical mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Editing-Characters.html#Editing-Characters)

Answer (score 1):

This is done by writing certain special control characters to stdout, which can do things like set the color, move the cursor, etc. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code for more info.
However, if you want your editor to be portable, or you don't want to worry yourself with details, you may want to consider using the ncurses library (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), which editors like nano/vi use rather than doing it themselves.